# Java mysql intercepting connections

Tags: java, mysql, sql

im building a project in Java, and I have a doubt in the connection. I'm jbdc to connect to a external mysql server. My problem is: Can a hacker, intercept my connection and find my database user and password?

If yes, how can I dodge this?

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site! This isn't a great question for StackOverflow. I recommend you read [the entire Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and head back when you have a specific, programming-related question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word "secure" depends on how you code it. JDBC security level is comparatively high than many other options but you should make sure that there is no venerability in your codes.

While coding, do not forget:

1. Use [prepared](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) statements.
2. Always use field validators.
3. Keep studying on building security systems.

Also, if your transport is not encrypted, then there is laways a chance of hacking. A SSL connection encrypts the transport and therefore enhanced the security.